# Query a Spring Data Rest repository with a HATEOAS link?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

If a client sends my API a HATEOAS link in an object to reference some entity like:

```
{
      "someLink": "http://localhost:8080/someResource/1"
}
```

Can I query the `someResource` repository using this link?

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why you wouldn't be able to.

You could hit the repository with a server side HTTP client after pulling the link in the controller and return the output or deserialize the link and hit the repository yourself if the controller can acquire reference to it.